# Log Shipping Monitor Stored Procedure returning Null

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-shipping

I have log shipping setup.  When I `EXEC sp_log_shipping _monitor` it returns all null values
even though log shipping appears to be working fine.

```
last_restored_file
NULL 

last_copied_file
NULL
```

Comment: I see the same thing as well as when I run the built-in report for Log Shipping Status.  I've verified that the jobs are running successfully and the files have been backed up, copied, and restored.